# I'm trying selenium to take screenshots of different websites but there is a popup obscuring the website

Tags: selenium

```
from PIL import Image 
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\arush\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.codingninjas.com/');

# options = Options()
# options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

# browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\arush\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

# driver.implicitly_wait(1000)
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/jdiv/jdiv/jdiv[3]/jdiv[1]/jdiv/jdiv').click()

# driver.implicitly_wait(100)
# time.sleep(10)
driver.save_screenshot(r"C:\Users\arush\OneDrive\Desktop\screenshots\cn.png");

driver.quit()

image = Image.open(r"C:\Users\arush\OneDrive\Desktop\screenshots\cn.png") 
  
# Showing the image 
image.show()
```

But problem is some websites have a pop-up box, how do i get a screenshot after closing the popup box.

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell selenium to close the popup. first you need to find the html element for the close button. then click the button using selenium.

i assume it is a html popup and not a javascript `alert()` popup.

to find the html element: open the website as human. see the popup box. see the close button. right click on the element and select "inspect element" or something similar. the developer tools of your browser should open showing the html source with the close button element highlighted.

now write the code for selenium to find the close button element. usually looks something like this:

```
closebutton = driver.find_element_by_id('some id')
```

(if you are lucky and the element has an id)

or

```
closebutton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('some horribly long xpath expression')
```

then click the button

```
closebutton.click()
```

then do the screenshot

if the popup is a javascript popup you can close it like this

```
alertbox = driver.switch_to.alert
alertbox.accept()
```